# Undefined symbol for boost serialization extended type info when using swig to convert from C++ to tcl

Tags: serialization, boost, swig

Hi I'm writing the conversion from C++ to Tcl using Swig.  Compiling is fine, everything is fine until I load the resulting shared library.  It gives me error like this.

> couldn't load file "./Library.so": ./Library.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost13serialization13typeid_system27extended_type_info_typeid_012is_less_thanERKNS0_18extended_type_infoE

I've checked boost and this signature is in boost/serialization/extended_type_info.hpp.  But I already added this in my Common.h section and include it throughout.  Also I added -lboost_serialization during compilation but the issue doesn't go away.  Weird thing is I write a cpp test and it works fine in C++ domain.  I don't know what is going on.  Would you please help?

Thank you,

Below is my Common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H_
#define COMMON_H_

#include <cstddef>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/system.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/archive_exception.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/type_info_implementation.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/config.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/singleton.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp>
#include <boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp>

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible explanations.

0. First is if the Dll doesn't dynamically link `libboost_serialization.so` (e.g. using `-lboost_serialization`).
1. The second is if the version of the dynamic library found at runtime does not match the headers used when compiling.¹

You can probably start diagnosing this by doing

```
ldd lib_my_tcl_module.so
```

---

¹ Technically this might include different *configurations* of the same code, though a scan of the docs do not reveal any obvious flags/defines that could cause this. Nevertheless, check your compiler flags, especially anything related to RTTI

Comment: Thanks Sehe.  When I run the command you suggested.  I got these messages  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd25387000)libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd681d50000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /proj_pd/user_dev/binh/DEV/TOOLS/GCC_2023/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd681b32000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd681764000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd682500000).  From what I understand from the message is the version compatibility between GCC and Boost.  I have GCC verson installed as GCC 2023 and boost version 1.82.0.  Are they compatible?

Comment: GCC 2023 isn't a version, and yeah, they're almost always compatible. (That's not what #2 said though: it specifically  about compiling against a different version of the boost library than is found by the runtime loader.). However, your `ldd` output clearly suggests that you failed to link to the boost library in the first place. That'll do it. So, #1 of my answer seem to apply

Comment: Thanks Sehe, from your suggestion, I was able to solve the issue.  I was missing -lboost_serialization  while linking.  I was using -switch for compile instead and that was the reason for the issue.